# Rest Authentication - Token validation with a database look up Vs alternatives

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, token, endpoint

I read through several q&a on stackoverflow for implementing rest authentication. And in one of those questions found a sample code as well.
https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity/blob/master/src/main/java/net/dontdrinkandroot/example/angularrestspringsecurity/rest/AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.java

Most of the answers talked about having an interceptor and filtering every request based on the auth header (a token and a user id or login id) and comparing it with the ones stored in the database.

I am implementing an Order management system.
And my url looks like `http://myapi.com/customers/{customerId}/Orders/{OrderId}`

Currently it is `http` and we're setting up the `https` soon.

In the URL, I get the customer ID and the order ID. I do a quick look up in the database with the order id and customer id and if it returns some rows, I return a JSON.

Questions I have:

1. To protect this endpoint, I can have a security interceptor. But every time I'll have to validate the request against the database. What are my alternatives (cache?) to validate or authorize each requests?
2. This rest end point is consumed by an android app(angular js)client and a website (a php client). For mobile, I should not re generate token each time the user logs in. So I have configured the token expiry to 30 days. However for the website, it is a session token. How should one handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

What you need can be solved with [Oauth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

Your backend (REST-API) will require authenticated access to your API operations. In turn, your clients/front-end will need to issue authenticated requests when communicating with the backend. This is achieved by sending `access tokens`.

Although this could seem complex, it will be very useful for you to take a look at [Stormpath](http://stormpath.com). We have a quite a straightforward solution for this. Please take a look at [Using Stormpath for API Authentication](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/).

As a summary, your solution will look like this:

1. You will use the [Stormpath Java SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java) to easily delegate all your user-management needs.
2. In your front, when the user presses the login button, your front end will send the credentials securely to your backend-end thorough its REST API.

   2.1. By the way, Stormpath greatly enhances all the possibilities here. Instead of having your own login page, you can completely delegate the login/register functionality to Stormpath via its [IDSite](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/using-id-site/), or you can also delegate it to our [Servlet Plugin](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html). Stormpath also supports Google, Facebook, LinkedIn and Github login.
3. Your backend will then try to authenticate the user against the Stormpath Backend and will return an `access token` as a result:

   ```
   /** This code will throw an Exception if the authentication fails */
   public void postOAuthToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Application application = client.getResource(applicationRestUrl, Application.class);

       //Getting the authentication result
       AccessTokenResult result = (AccessTokenResult) application.authenticateApiRequest(request);

       //Here you can get all the user data stored in Stormpath
       Account account = accessTokenResult.getAccount();

       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
       response.setContentType("application/json");

       //Output the json of the Access Token
       response.getWriter().print(token.toJson());
       response.getWriter().flush();
   }
   ```
4. Then, for every authenticated request, your backend will do:

   ```
   /** This is your (now protected) exposed operation */ 
   public void getOrder(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Application application = client.getResource(applicationRestUrl, Application.class);

       OauthAuthenticationResult result = (OauthAuthenticationResult) application.authenticateOauthRequest(request).execute();

       System.out.println(result.getApiKey());
       System.out.println(result.getAccount());

       //Return what you need to return in the response
       doGetOrder(request, response);
   }
   ```

Please take a look [here](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/#exchanging-api-keys-for-oauth-20-tokens) for more information

Hope that helps!

Disclaimer, I am an active Stormpath contributor.